# Trigger jquery mobile page transition from function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to navigate from one page to another using jquery mobile page transition? 
Currently i have an input box that fires a function on focusout, like so;

```
$("#page1").on("focusout", "input", function(){
 alert("working");
}
```

What i would like to do is after the focusout function fires, i would like to take the user to another page, using jquery mobile's page navigtion. Normally i would use a button like so;

```
<a href="#page2">Next</a>
```

How can i fire the `#page2` from the focusout function?

Comment: do you mean to fire an alert("working") on page2?

Comment: no i want to take the user to page 2 after the input box

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's in the same page. It needs to be.

```
//Solution From Comments Below; Thanks!
$.mobile.pagecontainer( "change", "#page2", { transition:"slide" } );

//Original Answer Deprecated
$.mobile.changePage($('#page2'), {transition:"slide"});
```

Comment: I found this answer on google and thought I should mention that this is now deprecated. Use the following method: `$.mobile.pagecontainer( "change", "#page2", { transition:"slide" } );`

Answer (score 2):

To change page in jQuery mobile, use:

```
$.mobile.changePage("yourpage.html", {transition:"slide"});
```

where slide can be changed to other transitions

Comment: This didn't work. I got my alert on the focusout, but not the page change and transition. I am not using an external file, all my pages are on the same page, so i have `$.mobile.changePage("#page2", {transition:"slide"});` is this correct?

Comment: ok you cant use #page2 if #page2 is in a different file, what file is #page2 in? put that filename instead of #page2 => $.mobile.changePage("page2file.html", {transition:"slide"});